# What is Winter Bash and Hats?

Tags: support

I can't access code-golf because of a problem. And when I entered, there is a winter bash. And hats. My question is:

1. What is winter bash and what is hats?
2. What is the purpose of that?
3. How it works?

Comment: it's just for fun for the winter holidays. they're basically like achievements in video games and if you earn one, you get a hat that can go on your avatar. if you look at my avatar you'll see a headset. that's not usually there but it's a hat that i earned.

Comment: "I can't access code-golf because of a problem." Uh... so are hats preventing you from doing something?

Comment: No, other one. That problem has no relation to the hats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) is an annual event across the entire Stack Exchange network, in which users can earn various hats that they can put on their avatars for completing certain tasks.
2. HATS!!!
3. On most sites, you will automatically be opted into Winter Bash. Simply visit [the home page](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) to see which hats you can earn. Once you've earned some hats, you can wear them by going to your profile.

Comment: Then what's the difference of hats and achievement?

Comment: And what do you mean with screaming "HATS!!!"?

Comment: @ChristianIrwan Hats are temporary and go away after January 4, as they're just meant as a bit of fun for the holidays and whatnot. As for your second question... HATS!!!

Comment: It's also important to note that you can opt out of Winter Bash entirely. You won't accrue hats nor will you see anyone else's.